# why 'onfocus' does not work on multiple select option, and 'onclick' does?

Tags: javascript, html

I do not see why onfocus='myFunction()' works in a an input, but not in an option, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onfocus="myFunction()">
```

calls myFunction when you click on it or when you tab into it, but:

```
<select multiple>
<option onfocus="myFunction()">whatever</option>
</select>
```

Does not work when you step in the option.

Why is this? I cannot find a documentation which says what events work on what elements. I have seen this for a long time, but now I want to know why

EDIT:
I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the [MDM web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus)

> For onfocus to fire on non-input elements, they must be given the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-tabindex) attribute

So in other terms: give the option with the focus event a tabIndex! The example below should work.

```js
function myFunction() {
      console.log("focus");
}

function myFunction2() {
      console.log("focus2");
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
    <option tabIndex="0" onfocus="myFunction()">whatever</option>
    <option tabIndex="0" onfocus="myFunction2()">whatever2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, that acutally does not work.  It's not called when you click it or move the arrows into it.

Comment: @Samuel It works in Firefox, but since you told me it doesn't work I tested it in a chromium based browser and it doesn't work there. Not sure if there is a way to let it work in both browsers...